# In libtidy, how to read string-valued options

Tags: c++, tidy

I am using `libtidy` and need to retrieve the current value of a string-based option (for example, [`TidyOptErrFile`, a.k.a. `error-file`](http://api.html-tidy.org/tidy/quickref_5.2.0.html#error-file)).

Even after reading through the [`tidy` source code](https://github.com/htacg/tidy-html5), I cannot figure out which function to use to *read* the current value of such an option.

The `TidyOptGetVal()` function seemed promising, but no matter what I do, it always returns a null pointer. Here is my minimalist attempt (in C++ so I can use the `auto` keyword):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tidy.h>
#include <tidybuffio.h>
#include <tidyenum.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    auto tidyDoc = tidyCreate();


    // The following should set the `error-file` property to `Foobar`
    tidyOptParseValue(tidyDoc, "TidyErrFile", "Foobar");

    // The type is `ctmbstr` which is just an alias for `const char*`
    auto errorFile = tidyOptGetValue(tidyDoc, TidyErrFile);

    if (errorFile==nullptr) {

        cout << "Null pointer" << endl;

    } else {

        cout << errorFile << endl;

    }

    tidyRelease(tidyDoc);

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason for the problem, which I will post for future reference.

The function `tidyOptParseValue()` takes as its second argument the *name of the option as given in the API*.

So, for example, the option name in this case should be `error-file` (not the name of the enumeration found in the source code).

The corrected line should be

```
    tidyOptParseValue(tidyDoc, "error-file", "Foobar");
```

Using that fix, the word `Foobar` is printed, as expected.